# Hibernate4 Session Factory is not getting autowired into DAO in spring 4.2.5,

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-mvc, spring-orm

```
##context.xml  ## 

<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context" 
        xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
        xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx.xsd">

      <bean id="hiberDataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp2.BasicDataSource">
            <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
            <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/DB" />
            <property name="username" value="root" />
            <property name="password" value="root" />
        </bean>

        <bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
            <property name="dataSource" ref="hiberDataSource"/>
            <property name="annotatedClasses">
                <list>
                    <value>com.basemodel.model.Ground</value>
                </list>
            </property>
            <property name="hibernateProperties">
                <props>
                    <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</prop>
                    <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
                </props>
            </property>
        </bean>
        <bean name="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager">
        <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
        <context:annotation-config />
    <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager" />      
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.basemodel.dao, com.basemodel.model" />
    </bean>
    </beans>
```

##  DAO Class: ##
        package com.basemodel.dao;

```
    import java.util.ArrayList;
    import java.util.List;

    import org.hibernate.Session;
    import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
    import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
    import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

    import com.basemodel.model.Ground;
    import com.basemodel.model.NewsFeed;

    @Component
    public class FeedListDAO {

        @Autowired
        private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

        public void setSessionFactory(SessionFactory sessionFactory)
        {
            this.sessionFactory = sessionFactory;
        }

        public List<NewsFeed> getNewsFeed() {
            List<NewsFeed> feedList = new ArrayList<NewsFeed>();
            for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
                NewsFeed feed = new NewsFeed();
                feed.setPostedby("" + i);
                feed.setMediaType("TEXT");
                feed.setPostContentMessage("We are part of the CB");
                feedList.add(feed);
            }
            Ground ground = new Ground();
            ground.setArea("Medavakkam");
            Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
            session.persist(ground);
            //getHibernateTemplate().save(ground);
            return feedList;

        }

    }
```

## Description: ##
        I am using Spring mvc, multimodule maven  project and my each module have individual spring context configuration file and loading them using contextconfiglocation classpath:context.xml (all config files in each module is named context.xml)

```
    Am getting an error while tomcat is starting up only when I am looking to wire the hibernate session factory, if I remove the same in my DAO, tomcat is starting up the rest call is getting inside.

   ## error details ##

    SEVERE: Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
    org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'feedListDAO': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private org.hibernate.SessionFactory com.basemodel.dao.FeedListDAO.sessionFactory; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [org.hibernate.SessionFactory] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:334)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1214)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:543)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:772)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:839)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:538)
        at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:444)
        at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:326)
        at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:107)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4812)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5255)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:147)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1408)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1398)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
    Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private org.hibernate.SessionFactory com.basemodel.dao.FeedListDAO.sessionFactory; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [org.hibernate.SessionFactory] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:573)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:88)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:331)
        ... 22 more
    Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [org.hibernate.SessionFactory] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.raiseNoSuchBeanDefinitionException(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1373)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1119)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1014)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:545)
        ... 24 more
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Slightly Redesign your BASEDAO class**

1. Please create a constructor arguments to set SessionFactory like this

   ```
               @Autowired
                   public FeedListDAO(SessionFactory sessionFactory) {
                       super(YourModel.class);
                       super.setSessionFactory(sessionFactory);
                   }
   ```
2. You should define your BASEDAO like below Example.

   ```
                       import java.io.Serializable;
                   import java.util.List;
                   import java.util.Map;

                   import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
                   import org.springframework.orm.ObjectRetrievalFailureException;
                   import org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTemplate;

                   import com.XX.XXXXIBaseDAO;

                   /**
                    * Base class for all hibernate DAO implementations
                    * extend this class only when your require custom CRUD logic.
                    *
                    * @param <T> a type variable
                    * @param <PK> the primary key for that type
                    */
                   @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
                   public class BaseDAOImpl<T, PK extends Serializable> implements IBaseDAO<T, PK> {

                       /**
                        * Log variable for all child classes.
                        */
                       private final Class<T> persistentClass;
                       private HibernateTemplate hibernateTemplate;


                       private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

                       /**
                        * Constructor that takes in a class to see which type of entity to persist.
                        * Use this constructor when subclassing.
                        *
                        * @param persistentClass the class type you'd like to persist
                        */
                       public BaseDAOImpl(final Class<T> persistentClass) {
                           this.persistentClass = persistentClass;
                       }

                       /**
                        * Constructor that takes in a class and sessionFactory for easy creation of DAO.
                        *
                        * @param persistentClass the class type you'd like to persist
                        * @param sessionFactory  the pre-configured Hibernate SessionFactory
                        */
                       public BaseDAOImpl(final Class<T> persistentClass, SessionFactory sessionFactory) {
                           this.persistentClass = persistentClass;
                           this.sessionFactory = sessionFactory;
                           this.hibernateTemplate = new HibernateTemplate(sessionFactory);
                       }

                       public HibernateTemplate getHibernateTemplate() {
                           return this.hibernateTemplate;
                       }

                       public SessionFactory getSessionFactory() {
                           return this.sessionFactory;
                       }

                       public void setSessionFactory(SessionFactory sessionFactory) {
                           this.sessionFactory = sessionFactory;
                           this.hibernateTemplate = new HibernateTemplate(sessionFactory);
                       }

                       /**
                        * {@inheritDoc}
                        */
                       public List<T> getAll() {
                           return hibernateTemplate.loadAll(this.persistentClass);
                       }

                       /**
                        * {@inheritDoc}
                        */
                       public T get(PK id) {
                           T entity = (T) hibernateTemplate.get(this.persistentClass, id);
                           if (entity == null) {
                               throw new ObjectRetrievalFailureException(this.persistentClass, id);
                           }
                           return entity;
                       }

                       /**
                        * {@inheritDoc}
                        */
                       public boolean exists(PK id) {
                           T entity = (T) hibernateTemplate.get(this.persistentClass, id);
                           return entity != null;
                       }

                       /**
                        * {@inheritDoc}
                        */
                       public T save(T object) {
                           T obj = (T) hibernateTemplate.save(object);
                           hibernateTemplate.flush();
                           return obj; 
                       }

                       /**
                        * {@inheritDoc}
                        */
                       public void saveorUpdate(T object) {
                          hibernateTemplate.saveOrUpdate(object);
                          hibernateTemplate.flush(); 
                       }

                       /**
                        * {@inheritDoc}
                        */
                       public void delete(PK id) {
                           hibernateTemplate.delete(this.get(id));
                           hibernateTemplate.flush();
                       }


                       public void update(T object) {
                           hibernateTemplate.update(object);
                           hibernateTemplate.flush();
                       }

                       public List<T> findByQuery(String queryString, Map<String, Object> queryParams) {
                           String[] params = new String[queryParams.size()];
                           Object[] values = new Object[queryParams.size()];

                           int index = 0;
                           for (String s : queryParams.keySet()) {
                               params[index] = s;
                               values[index++] = queryParams.get(s);
                           }
                           return hibernateTemplate.findByNamedParam(queryString, params, values);
                       }
                   }
   ```
3. IBASEDAO interface given below.

   ```
                        import java.io.Serializable;
                       import java.util.List;
                       import java.util.Map;


                       /**
                        * Generic DAO with common methods for CRUD operations.
                        *
                        * <p>Extend this interface if you want typesafe DAO's
                        * (no casting necessary)
                        *
                        * @param <T> a type variable
                        * @param <PK> the primary key for that type
                        */
                       public interface IBaseDAO <T, PK extends Serializable> {

                           /**
                            * Generic method used to get all objects of a particular type. This
                            * is the same as lookup up all rows in a table.
                            * @return List of populated objects
                            */
                           List<T> getAll();

                           /**
                            * Generic method to get an object based on class and identifier. An
                            * ObjectRetrievalFailureException Runtime Exception is thrown if
                            * nothing is found.
                            *
                            * @param id the identifier (primary key) of the object to get
                            * @return a populated object
                            * @see org.springframework.orm.ObjectRetrievalFailureException
                            */
                           T get(PK id);

                           /**
                            * Checks for existence of an object of type T using the id arg.
                            * @param id the id of the entity
                            * @return - true if it exists, false if it doesn't
                            */
                           boolean exists(PK id);

                           /**
                            * Generic method to save an object - handles both update and insert.
                            * @param object the object to save
                            * @return the persisted object
                            */
                           T save(T object);

                           /**
                            * Generic method to save or Update an object - handles both update and insert.
                            * @param object the object to save
                            * @return the persisted object
                            */
                           void saveorUpdate(T object);

                           /**
                            * Generic method to delete an object based on class and id
                            * @param id the identifier (primary key) of the object to remove
                            */
                           void delete(PK id);

                           /**
                            * Generic method to get an object based on class and identifier. An
                            * ObjectRetrievalFailureException Runtime Exception is thrown if
                            * nothing is found.
                            *
                            * @param queryString, queryParams used to get
                            * @return a populated object
                            * @see org.springframework.orm.ObjectRetrievalFailureException
                            */
                           List<T> findByQuery(String queryString, Map<String, Object> queryParams) ;
                       }

                   }
   ```
4. Your Final Implementation should be like this.

   ```
               @Repository
           public class FeedListDAOImpl extends BaseDAOImpl<YourModel.class, Integer> implements FeedListDAO{

               private static final Logger LOG = Logger.getLogger(FeedListDAOImpl .class);

               @Autowired
               public FeedListDAOImpl (SessionFactory sessionFactory) {
                   super(YourModel.class);
                   super.setSessionFactory(sessionFactory);
               }
   ```
5. Please make the above changes,it is mainly for better abstraction of DAO classes. Hope this should work 100%

Comment: @Marimuthu, please let know if you have tried above option

Comment: Still the same error, the problem is session factory is not getting instantiated from the context and hence the wiring mechanism is not able to find the bean of type sessionFactory, please have a look at the context.xml I have provided and please provide suggestions for the fix

Comment: the session factory is getting created when run as stand alone but not when the tomcat is starting, does that mean that all my contexts in the classpath is not loading???

Comment: @Mari,Looked at your context.xml file, your ref should be dataSource not hibernateDatasource,  please change accordingly and let know